# How to replace and correct json path string with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, json, jsonpath

I have a javascript array of strings, with modified json path just, like this:

```
55-fathers-2-married
55-fathers-2-name
55-fathers-2-sons
55-fathers-1-id
55-fathers-1-married
55-fathers-1-name
55-fathers-1-daughters2-2-age
55-fathers-1-daughters2-2-name
55-fathers-1-daughters2-1-age
55-fathers-1-daughters2-1-name
55-fathers-1-daughters2-0-age
55-fathers-1-daughters2-0-name
55-fathers-1-sons-0
55-fathers-1-sons-1
55-fathers-1-sons-2
55-fathers-0-id-somethingelse
```

How can i change all elements from this list, to become a valid json path ? I mean something like this :

```
[55].fathers[2].married
[55].fathers[2].name
[55].fathers[2].sons
[55].fathers[1].id
[55].fathers[1].married
[55].fathers[1].name             
[55].fathers[1].daughters2[2].age
[55].fathers[1].daughters2[2].name
[55].fathers[1].daughters2[1].age
[55].fathers[1].daughters2[1].name
[55].fathers[1].daughters2[0].age
[55].fathers[1].daughters2[0].name
[55].fathers[1].sons[0]
[55].fathers[1].sons[1]
[55].fathers[1].sons[2]
[55].fathers[0].id.somethingelse
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
json.replace(/-/g, '.').replace(/(^|\.)([0-9]+)($|\.)/g, '[$2]$3');
```

1. Replace the dashes with periods
2. Search for all numbers within periods or at the beginning or end of a line. Surround those results with brackets. Then add the period ($3) after the bracket if necessary.

Comment: beautiful regex, could use some explanation for those not very familiar with regexes though

Comment: Yeah sorry, I got dragged away from my computer temporarily.

Comment: i ran the code, that was almost there, its missing a '.' after ']' .. it should be [55].fathers[2].married not [55]fathers[2]married

Comment: Right you are. Didn't notice that. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
str.replace(/([a-z]+)/gi, ".$1").replace(/(\d+)/gi, "[$1]").replace(/-/g, '');
```

Comment: did not work when a field had a number between it. Ex:
"55-multivalorado-1-data45-0" became ->> "[55].multivalorado[1].data[45][0]"