# Perform Simple Javascript Regex in Python

Tags: javascript, python, regex

How to perform this javascript regex into Python (3.2)?

```
exmple_string.replace(/-/g, '.').replace(/(^|\.)([0-9]+)($|\.)/g, '[$2]$3');
```

The regex should work as following:

[How to replace and correct json path string with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17796269/how-to-replace-and-correct-json-path-string-with-regex)

I tried the re library, but don't know how to peform the periods [$2]$3

Comment: Have you looked at [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)?  It should be pretty straight-forward. . .

Comment: I've tried 
`u = pattern.replace('-', '.')`
`v = re.sub(r'(^|\.)([0-9]+)($|\.)', r'[$2]$3', u)` but got no success, the periods do not work

Comment: In python, use a slash instead of dollar to refer to groups: `r[\2]\3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the re library. https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/re.html

```
import re

value = "55-fathers-2-married"
value = value.replace("-", ".")
re.sub(r"(^|\.)([0-9]+)($|\.)", r"[\2]\3", value)
```

Test your regex with the python regex tool. http://www.pythonregex.com/